# Google Jquery API ping?

Tags: jquery, html

If I use Googles Jquery load script  inlink, then if the user has the file already in their cache, will the users computer still contact Google in **ANY** way when the page loads?

Example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the cache settings of the browser, the cache headers sent by the server when the file was originally loaded, and the time since the file was last loaded, the browser may still issue the request with a If-Modified-Since HTTP header - which would result in a HTTP 304 "Not Modified" response if the file was not modified server-side since it was originally received by the browser / client.

The HTTP headers being returned by Google for this URL are a bit interesting, though its been a while since I've had to deal with the specifics of this:

```
$ curl -i http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 18:58:43 GMT
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 15:18:56 GMT
Expires: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 15:18:56 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: public,max-age=31536000
Age: 518244
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The Date, Last-Modified, and Expires are all in the past - so I read this to mean that it expires immediately.  Yet, there are Cache-Control and Age headers which should allow this to be cached for 1 year (31536000 seconds) - if http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9 is being followed as required.

Comment: For "normal"/default browser settings, is that then a no?

Comment: It depends.  I'd experiment with it and try it out.  Also, note Iljaas's comment / answer - the user can always force a refresh.  +1 for copying the library and hosting it off of your own server.

Comment: I don't mind if they're notified sometimes, but I don't want Google to be getting full analytics for my website + traffic data.

Comment: I think (but I'm not entirely sure) that based on these headers the browser should always contact google to check whether the file can still be used, but the file does not actually have to be downloaded. If this is the case, than google could still build statistics of your website (because their server is contacted) without having to send the file.

Comment: @ziesemer: I've repeated the `curl` command from your post and in the headers it says `Expires: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 19:24:00 GMT`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the browser to contact google upon loading the site, why don't you copy jquery to your server?

I mean cache can be disabled in the user's browser. Also, the user can force a refresh. And there are some http headers which may force the browser to contact google to refresh the file.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as is. If the user has a copy in their browser cache from google's CDN (very likely) then it will not download another copy, if they don't it will.